# Thumbs up gem not working appropriately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

So I've been working on this project, however the thumbs up gem that I'm using for the voting system isn't working correctly.

If you go to www.leapfm.com you'll see that for some reason even a song with 2 votes is ranked below a song with 1 vote. Which doesn't make sense.

Now you might think upload date plays a role, but in this case it doesn't. I've uploaded a brand new song and made two accounts to vote it up twice but it was still below the song with 1 vote.

What can I do to get this workin' ?

**the code**

index.html.erb snippit

```
  <%=link_to image_tag('arrow.gif'), vote_for_song_path(song), :remote => true, :method => :put  if controller.action_name == "index" %>
```

**song_controller.rb snippit**

```
def vote_for
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      @song.plusminus = @song.votes_for
      @song.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_votes' }
      end
  end

  # GET /Songs
  # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    if params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    else      
      @songs = Song.order('plusminus').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    end
  end
```

the gem [HERE](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs you should try:

`@songs` `=` `Song.plusminus_tally.order('plusminus_tally DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)`

Comment: okay that seems to work, however, now pagination isn't working? hmm

Comment: how can we get paginate to work also? the more button at the buttom for paginate disapeared www.leapfm.com

Comment: I'd have to know more about your setup. Are you using a gem?

Comment: using will_paginate for pagination, see here for specific details :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052184/paginate-not-working-with-thumbs-up-gem